# Rails 5 - Devise + Petergate - Admin edit other user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have found some related questions but they don't seem to work for my case, they are either for older versions or don't fit my approach.

I have set up a User model with devise and it has two related models, it has one Contact Detail and many Addresses. I also have Petergate to get the roles.

I want any user to edit their registration (I have added contact details and addresses at the app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb form) and admin can edit all.

The button in the contact details show page is implemented like this:

`<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path(@contact_detail.user) if logged_in?(:admin) || current_user.id == @contact_detail.user_id %>`

and the edit form is the following

```
h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
...
...
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact_detail do |contact_detail|%>
      <%= render "contact_detail_fields", f: contact_detail %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address_form| %>
      <%= render "address_fields", f: address_form %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

But when I click the button on a user's contact details page, I always redirect to the admins edit page (/users/edit.1) and not to the user's edit page.

How can edit I the correct user's registration path?

My routes.rb file has the following:

```
  resources :addresses
  resources :contact_details
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'my_registrations'
  }
```

I haven't made a users controller override and my models don't contain anything relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An admin section where you can CRUD other users is not actually a feature of Devise.

The Devise RegistrationsController is built from the ground up to only work for the current user. The routes are actually singular and don't contain an id segment. You would have to override pretty much everything to get it working and in the process you're steamrolling the Single Responsibility Principle.

If you want to CRUD other users just create a seperate route and controller just like you would for any other resource. You can just run `rails g scaffold_controller users` to scaffold one.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'my_registrations'
}
resources :users
```

If you want to share view code between registrations and your users controller don't try to recycle your `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` view. Instead spit the view into partials that can be resused.

```
# app/views/users/_fields.html.erb
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact_detail do |contact_detail|%>
      <%= render "contact_detail_fields", f: contact_detail %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address_form| %>
      <%= render "address_fields", f: address_form %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  # ...

# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(user) do |f| >
  <%= render "users/fields", f: f %>
  <%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

# app/views/users/new/html.erb
<%= render "form", user: @user %>

# app/views/users/new/edit.erb
<%= render "form", user: @user %>

# app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
# This might be broken due to your earlier modifications so might want to  
# regenerate the views 
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, method: :put do|f| %>
  <%= render "users/fields", f: f %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

While you can explicitly render another view by passing a path in the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render 'devise/registrations/edit', 
      locals: { resource: @user, resource_name: :user }
  end
end
```

This really just pushes the complexity down into the view layer. Editing your own account and someone else account is not the same thing and the view will end up full of conditionals sooner or later.

Comment: Ok, I got the logic. Then, I should put edit_user_path(@contact_detail.user) at the button and it will lead me to /users/10/edit for example. But the registrations edit form won't render, it will redirect to app/views/user/edit.html.erb file, right? Should I create this file and then just render the form there, or is there a better way to render the registrations edit form there?What is the way to do it?

Comment: Use partials instead to share code  (the fields) between your users forms and the registrations form. Don't try to shoehorn any of the devise stuff into this. The devise code is really overcomplicated since it has to make so few assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your last comment. Can you make it a bit simpler? Could you walk me through with the steps I need to take, please? I shouldn't use the registration form on the app/views/users/edit file that I will create?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm saying. I edited the question with examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!